# Solving $f(x)$ in a functional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> Find of general form for $f(x)$ given $f(x)+xf\left(\displaystyle\frac{3}{x}\right)=x.$

I think we need to substitute $x$ as something else, but I'm not sure. Will $x=\displaystyle\frac{3}{x}$ help me?

Comment: It should.  Why don't you try it?

Comment: But why substitute $x=3/x$, how do we determine which substitution is useful or not?

Comment: Notice that $3/(3/x) = x$, so this gives you another equation involving the same $f(x)$ and $f(3/x)$.  If you can eliminate the $f(3/x)$ from the two equations, you have a chance of being able to solve for $f(x)$.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you!

Comment: Peek at Evan Chen's ["Introduction to Functional Equations"](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf), a lucid discussion on how to tackle functional equations in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it helps, as follows:

From
$$f(x)+xf(\frac{3}{x})=x\tag{*}$$
we get
$$f(\frac{3}{x})+\frac{3}{x}f(x)=\frac{3}{x}$$
or
$$xf(\frac{3}{x})+3f(x)=3\tag{**}$$
from (*) anf (**), we have:
$$-2f(x)=x-3$$
or $$f(x)=\frac{3-x}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+\frac{3}{x}f(x)=\frac{3}{x}$$
Thus, putting this expression of $f(x/3)$ in the first equation gives
$$f(x)=x-xf(3/x)=x+3f(x)-3$$
We finally have $f(x)=\frac{3-x}{2}$ and this function satisfies your equation.